# render four button on each item in flatlist programmatically react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching data from API and data is coming in below form

```
data : [
        {
          source1: { number: 1,title: '', content: ''},
          source2: { number: 2, title: '',content: ''},
          source3: { number: 4,  title: '',content: '' },
          id: '1',
          title: '',
        },
        {
          source1: { number: 1,title: '', content: ''},
          source2: { number: 2, title: '',content: ''},
          source3: { number: 4,  title: '',content: '' },
          id: '2',
          title: '',
        }
      ]
```

> I want to show on Flatlist and what i want from this that

[image: Pictruie]

**Four button are there.**

**When click on one the text will be changed and also button style will be updated.   Button tittle and chaning text will come from data -> soruce 1 (button 1) source2 (button 2) source3 (button 3) soruce 4 (button 4) .   for single item**

> Help me how can implement this each render item on flatlist or through map()?

thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use Flatlist for this?Looks like a conditional rendering for me

Comment: Also why is there 3 source1 keys inside data object/

Comment: no problem if you want to give answer through map() . you can

Comment: sorry my mistake,      i've updated question

Comment: @ThakurKarthik .Please have a look on updated question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to maintain an activeSource/activeItem in the data and update it on source change from Touchable/Button.This way it will be easy to maintain the active source per item.

```
data: [
 {source1:'',source2:'',source3:'',...,activeSource:'source1',id:1,Title:''},
 {source1:'',source2:'',source3:'',...,activeSource:'source1',id:2,Title:''},
 {source1:'',source2:'',source3:'',...,activeSource:'source1',id:3,Title:''},
 ...
]
```

Change the activeSource from the Touchable from the item index which you get in renderItem prop

`renderItem=(({item,index})=>{...})`

The onChange will look something like this

```
changeSource = (source, itemIndex) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: prevState.data.map((item, index) => {
        if (index !== itemIndex) return item;
        return {
          ...item,
          activeSource: source,
        };
      }),
    }));
  };
```

And render corresponding source item as

```
<Text>{item[item[activeSource]]}</Text
```

Iam attaching an expo [link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/touchable-source-flatlist)

Comment: what does exactly meaning by active source ?

Comment: Since you are having different sources like source1,source2,... in the item of data array,an active source tells which source's data should be displayed,This is done as item[item[activeSource]]==>here item[activeSource] will contain key of source.check out the expo link.

Comment: Your code is very tuff. We are still trying to understand

Comment: just keep an variable called activeSource for each data item in the state..Then update this activeSource to the available sources like activeSource=source1/source2/... and render the data associated with that source in the renderItem prop..am i clear?

Comment: thank you so much . You helped me . it worked like charm.    and also thanks to those who devote my question

Comment: Good to know that it helped !